# ssh from A to C via B box using A key without storing it on B machine

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm working on script to connect to C machine from A through B using only one key.

So I want to do something like this:

```
ssh -t -i id_rsa user@b_box ssh -i id_rsa user@c_box
```

The problem is that I want to store id_rsa only on my localhost. Is there any way to pass this key as a parameter or variable to B machine so I can connect to C box without password?

I want to be able to login without password to more than 30 boxes (maybe more in future) from B machine. This is easy when I store my key on B box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what we have `ProxyCommand` for:

```
ssh -i id_rsa -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user@b_box" user@c_box
```

or rather in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host b_box
  User user
  IdentityFile /path/to/id_rsa
Host c_box
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p b_box
  User user
  IdentityFile /path/to/id_rsa
```

and then connect just with `ssh c_box`.

Comment: It's working great. Thanks for help! Now I just need to create script to fill config with my server list!